# Flutter || How to do many UI changes in a single container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

How can I achieve this UI?

[image]

want to change the UI in same container
I was thinking of using a bool variable that will change when I will click a button but using this with setstate will hit the performance

is there any easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Take you container in separate stateful class and use setState inside that class,
moreover don't worry about performance related issue with setState, SetState only updates Element tree it does not recreate it.

Comment: but still is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: You are doing it right.